# Linq to Objects: TakeWhileOrFirst

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

What would be the most readable way to apply the following to a sequence using linq:

```
TakeWhile elements are valid but always at least the first element
```

EDIT: I have updated the title, to be more precise. I'm sorry for any confusion, the answers below have definitely taught me something!

The expected behavior is this: Take while element are valid. If the result is an empty sequence, take the first element anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question. See edits. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be most efficiently implemented manually as far as I can tell to ensure that it isn't enumerated over more than necessary.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileOrFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        TSource current = enumerator.Current;
        yield return current;
        if (predicate(current))
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext() && predicate(current = enumerator.Current))
                yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the sake of completion, an overload that includes the index:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileOrFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        TSource current = enumerator.Current;
        int index = 0;
        yield return current;
        if (predicate(current, index++))
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext() && predicate(current = enumerator.Current, index++))
                yield return current;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just deleted a similar answer: it's wrong. If the first item doesn't match the predicate, we should yield it out and stop. This doesn't do that.

Comment: @Ani: I'm not sure which interpretation of the question is _the_ right one.  But I think "always at least the first element" could mean, "always the head element at least" and doesn't necessarily have to match the condition.  If the other way, it would have been better worded, "at least one element that matches the condition."  I think we were fine unless the OP clarifies.  I'll see if I can come up with a way to address that interpretation and include it in my answer if someone doesn't get to it first.

Comment: I guess. My reasoning was based purely on how I would interpret "TakeWhileButAtLeastOne" without context. :)

Comment: Ï really can't interprete the question to mean always take the first element ând any following that matches. This will fail if the first îs a non match but the following are matches

Comment: @Rune: I can't possibly be at fault here.  It's an answer to an interpretation of a question that wasn't clearly defined.  _If_ that was the intended behavior, it should have been stated more clearly.  This is what Ani and I were discussing.  And as asgerhallas isn't around right now to clarify, it should be open to interpretation until he does.

Comment: There's limits to interpretation lest it becomes a reinterpretation. I believe TakeWhileAtLeastOne is why to different from TakeFirstAndAllTheFollowingThatMatches to call that a interpretation

Comment: I'm here now after a nights sleep :) Thanks a lot for all the answers! I'm sorry that the question wasn't quite clear, my interpretation is this: always the head element at least and it doesn't necessarily have to match the condition." ... but if that head element doesn't match the condition then stop!

Comment: The answer from Botz3000 does this well, BUT this answer from Jeff M has great advantage if the source sequence can only be iterated once. Well done!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Marked as answer. Have a nice day, sir! :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this makes the intention quite clear:

```
things.TakeWhile(x => x.Whatever).DefaultIfEmpty(things.First());
```

My earlier, more verbose solution:

```
var query = things.TakeWhile(x => x.Whatever);
if (!query.Any()) { query = things.Take(1); }
```

Comment: I don't think it makes it less readable.  It's just the way to do it using the functional paradigm (which LINQ allows us to do).  If you have no exposure to functional code but only procedural code, then yes it probably would be considered "unreadable" but for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: By saying unreadable, i was meaning "not making the original intention clear". Functional code can be perfectly readable if done right. But i must admit there are indeed one-liners in this case that are making the intention clear.

Comment: Ah that's a good update.  I always seem to forget about those operations when not dealing with writing outer joins.

Comment: This doesn't take into account queries that can only be enumerated once though. I think your solution does, but i'm not sure if the index overload works for e.g. ObjectResult<T>.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. That "can only be enumerated once" is indeed a important. Good point!

Answer (score 4):

The following works*, and seems pretty well readable to me:

```
seq.Take(1).Concat(seq.TakeWhile(condition).Skip(1));
```

There may be a better way, not sure.

<sub>*with thanks to @Jeff M for the correction</sub>

Comment: You'd need an `IEnumerable<>` to `Concat()` to.  I'd use `Take(1)` instead of `First()`.

Comment: @Rune: Note that I skip the first value out of the taken set, rather than skipping the first value in the set and then taking while the condition is matched. If the first is a non-match and the following are, only the first will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:**
This is a variation of Jeff Ms nice answer and as such is only meant to show the code using do-while instead. It's only provided as an extension to Jeffs answer.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeWhileOrFirst<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var current = enumerator.Current; 
        do{
            yield return current
        } while (predicate(current) && 
                 enumerator.MoveNext() && 
                 predicate(current = enumerator.Current) );
    }
}
```

of course it's a matter of style I personally like to have as low a nesting level of my conditional logic as possible but the double use of predicate might be hard to grasp and can be a slight performance hog (depending on optimization and branch prediction)

Comment: If the low nesting level was a goal, I think it would have been cleanest with what I had (with a while loop), but instead, have a `yield break;` if the first check failed.

Comment: @Jeff I'm of the opinion that the more exit points you have (call them continue, return, goto or what ever is require by the language sepc) the harder it is to read and understand the code and the same goes for additional branching points. Both have been shown to increase the likelyhood of errors and with that in mind I think an extra if and an extra exit point has a negative impact